# In gae ndb, is there a similar functionality like cascading delete in relational database?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, foreign-keys, app-engine-ndb

Is cascading delete possible in gae ndb?
If so, how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such thing as ndb is not a relational database and if you want to achieve the same you will have to do that on your own. There is no specific way to implement this as it depends on your actual needs. As a general tip you might want to use [transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions) to make sure that all the related records will be gone before deleting the parent.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on transaction.

Comment: If there is the potential for large numbers of items in the cascade, you will need to think about strategies for making this perform, such as running the cascade delete in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I've found `ndb model` has the `_pre_delete_hook` and `_post_delete_hook` which could be used to treat this problem. [_pre_delete_hook](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass?hl=zh-cn#Model__pre_delete_hook)